# Ajax Pass Json to PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

I have looked at a few post but cant seem to work out what I've done incorrect, i need to work with the JSON to inport into database but it saying my posted cities is not coming through?

**Javascript**

```
     console.log(jsonData);
      $.ajax({
          url: "ajax.php",
          type: "post",
          data: jsonData,
      datatype: 'json',
          success: function(jsonData){  

               $('#result').html(jsonData);

          },
          error:function(){
              alert('ajax failed');    
          }   
        }); 
}
```

**Ajax.php**

```
$obj = json_decode($_POST['cities']);

print_r($obj);
```

**Error :**

Notice: Undefined index: cities in ajax.php on line 3

**Console Log for Json**

> {"currentCity":"Exeter","cities":[{"name":"Exeter","offers":[{"offer":"test","price":"11","notes":"100","city":"Exeter"}]}]}

Comment: There is no `cities` in the form post. `$var_dump($_POST);`

Comment: how do i get cities to it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well firstly, `datatype` needs to be `dataType`. Note that this follows the lower camel case nomenclature.

Secondly, `$_POST['cities'];` will not work because it is the key in a JSON object and not a key to a post identifier. What you need to do is pass it along like, `data: {'json' : jsonData}`, then you can do:

```
 $obj = json_decode($_POST['json']);
 print_r($obj['cities']);
```

**edit**

So your ajax call will look like below:

```
$.ajax({
     url: "ajax.php",
     type: "post",
     data: {
         "json" : jsonData
     },
     dataType: 'json',
     success: function(jsonData){  
          $('#result').html(jsonData);
     },
     error:function(){
         alert('ajax failed');    
     }   
});
```

Comment: Can you go into a little more detail on the {'json' : jsonData} I'm a little confused but thanks for speeding time in replying.

Comment: @BrentFrench So in this case, the actual JSON object that you've constructed is not a post identifier, it is a string that has key value pairs, but it is not a POST object. So what we're doing there is identifying that the `$_POST` key is `json` so that we can then grab it and then we can decode it's value.

Comment: I understand, but still cant get it to work, Would you be able to update your post with the correct change?